# SELECT COUNT Based on another row in the same table

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I select a **COUNT** based on **ANOTHER ROW** in the **SAME TABLE** so it doesn't count duplicate values?

I want to select the COUNT(id) as TOTAL, only ONCE per email.

**This is my starting point:**

```
SELECT COUNT(id) AS total 
FROM entries 
WHERE tracking_code = 'test2'
```

**What I'm trying to accomplish is something like this:**

```
SELECT COUNT(id) AS total 
FROM entries 
WHERE id IN (SELECT DISTINCT email FROM entries)
```

Comment: could you maybe put some example data from DB and what you actually expect as values ?

Comment: JREAM, could you edit your question to read "another column" rather than "another row"? It would make it more accurate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
select count(distinct email) from entries
```